# How to prove that a function only defined for integers (or primes, or multiples of 3, etc.) have a certain derivative?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I would like to know how a function not continuously defined (for a lack of better words) could be proven to have a certain derivative (or, if the word "derivative" isn't appropriate, rate of growth). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It can't and it doesnt.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean? E.g. what sort of applications are you hoping for? I can think of a couple topics that might be relevant, depending on what you're after.

Comment: As a project, I am trying to prove the prime number theorem.

Comment: How I am doing this is I am proving that $p_{n}-p_{n-1}$ has a non-constant derivative greater than $1$ when $n < 1$.

Comment: But you can, sometimes, come up with a formula f (n+1)=g (f (n)).  Depends on the function.  The smallest interval is one so the nearest to a derivative would be f (n+1)/f (n) (or maybe avg (f (n+1)/f (n)l which may or may not be meaningful, expressible, or useful.  It does work for exponential growth, but not much else.

Comment: Since $p_n-p_{n-1}$ occasionally decreases, you will have some difficulty finding a sensible notion of derivative which will be greater than zero.

Comment: The best thing I could do what some Mathematica number-crunching to find a quadratic fit for a smooth (from moving average) version of $p_x-p_{x-1}$.

Comment: The problem is that that isn't exactly a *proof*.

Answer (score 0):

For functions defined on integers, the analogue of the derivative is the finite difference operator $$ \left[D[f(m)]\right]_n \equiv f(n)-f(n-1)$$

A good book on finite math discusses and works with finite differences.  One of the best is Concrete Mathematics, by Knuth et. al.

But even a good knowledge of finite differences is nowhere near enough to prove the PNT.